# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup at runtime

Tags: gradle, visual-studio-code, grails, groovy, jsoup

I have a webapp: grails + groovy + gradle (vscode 1.59 as editor)

I get these errors at runtime:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup
```

build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
```

class file:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*
import static org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.*
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType
import java.io.File
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import groovy.sql.Sql
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.*
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element
import org.jsoup.select.Elements
```

Error line:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")
```

Things I tried (none worked):

- Make a fat jar.
- Disable gradle offline mode.
- Copy jsoup jar to lib dir.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: vscode terminal commands:
grails command
run-app command
windows 10 as OS

Comment: Have you added Jsoup in a different gradle module (implementation does not make it transitive depending on gradle version and applied plugins)

Comment: Nope. How is that?

Comment: I tried with api command and i get an error (gradle v5.1.1):
Error initializing classpath: Could not find method api() for arguments [org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like gradle files were corrupted.
I downloaded same version(5.1.1) for a "clean" install.
I set GRAILS_GRADLE_HOME system variable to the new clean gradle folder.

Now it works!